# Selecting only one minimum value for each repeating value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table like below:

```
CODE | DATA |
-----+------+--
asd  | 1    |
asd  | 2    |
asd2 | 3    |
asd4 | 3    |
asd4 | 2    |
```

I am trying to select the minimum `data` for each code, so that only one should be selected for the given code, wanted result is

```
CODE | DATA |
-----+------+--
asd  | 1    |
asd2 | 3    |
asd4 | 2    |
```

I have tried

```
Select code, min(data) from myTable group by code, data;
```

The result I get is only grouping of similar codes but not selecting the minimum of data only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just aggregate over the `code`, but not the data:

```
SELECT code, MIN(data) AS min_data
FROM myTable
GROUP BY code;
```

Comment: yup needed to group over single value, understood my mistake, thanks

Comment: @Hatik Nothing wrong with making mistakes ... in a sense we _are_ grouping over the data as well, but we are just selecting a minimum value from among all values for each code.